# NDK - Error trying to generate a build.xml file for Hello-jni

Tags: android, ant, build, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

I just installed `Android NDK, r5b`, and while trying to follow the steps from [Exploring the hello-jni Sample](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html), on the command line I receive the error:

```
MacBook-2:~ mvermant$ cd ndk/samples/hello-jni
MacBook-2:hello-jni mvermant$ android update project -p . -s
-bash: android: command not found
```

I'm using Eclipse Helios release 2 with `Android SDK r10` and `ADT 10.0.0` on MAC 10.6.6. I have also checked to have `GNU Make 3.81`, and installed `GNU Awk`(though I am not sure it's in the right place).

I've searched a lot, and ***seems there might be a class path missing*** somewhere, but I can't figure out where exactly and what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure the `tools` directory of your android-sdk is on your (shell) path.

Something like:

```
export PATH="/path/to/sdk/tools:$PATH"
```

before you execute your command.

In general you will also need two other directories to be on your path:

- `/path/to/sdk/platform-tools` - for adb and other android sdk tools
- `/path/to/ndk` - for ndk-build and ndk-gdb, which are ndk tools

You can also do some [setup](https://dennismillerdev.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/set-path-variable-on-mac-os-x/) so that you don't have to run these commands every time you open Terminal.

Comment: By including the other two paths, you mean exporting them also? Do I have to navigate to a specific directory before exporting them?

Comment: Yes, you use the same export statement, replacing /path/to/sdk/tools with /path/to/ndk etc.